# sum multiple columns by group with tapply

Tags: r, tapply

I wanted to sum individual columns by group and my first thought was to use `tapply`.
However, I cannot get `tapply` to work.  Can `tapply` be used to sum multiple columns?
If not, why not?

I have searched the internet extensively and found numerous similar questions posted
as far back as 2008.  However, none of those questions have been answered directly.
Instead, the responses invariably suggest using a different function.

Below is an example data set for which I wish to sum apples by state, cherries by state 
and plums by state.  Below that I have compiled numerous alternatives to `tapply` that
do work.

At the bottom I show a simple modification to the `tapply` source code that allows
`tapply` to perform the desired operation.

Nevertheless, perhaps I am overlooking a simple way to perform the desired operation
with `tapply`.  I am not looking for alternative functions, although additional alternatives are welcome.

Given the simplicity of my modification to the `tapply` source code I wonder why it, or
something similar, has not already been implemented.

Thank you for any advice.  If my question is a duplicate I will be happy to post my
question as an answer to that other question.

Here is the example data set:

```
df.1 <- read.table(text = '

    state   county   apples   cherries   plums
       AA        1        1          2       3
       AA        2       10         20      30
       AA        3      100        200     300
       BB        7       -1         -2      -3
       BB        8      -10        -20     -30
       BB        9     -100       -200    -300

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This does not work:

```
tapply(df.1, df.1$state, function(x) {colSums(x[,3:5])})
```

The help pages says:

```
tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE)

X       an atomic object, typically a vector.
```

I was confused by the phrase `typically a vector` which made me wonder whether
a data frame could be used.  I have never been clear on what `atomic object` means.

Here are several alternatives to `tapply` that do work.  The first alternative is a work-around that combines `tapply` with `apply`.

```
apply(df.1[,c(3:5)], 2, function(x) tapply(x, df.1$state, sum))

#    apples cherries plums
# AA    111      222   333
# BB   -111     -222  -333

with(df.1, aggregate(df.1[,3:5], data.frame(state), sum))

#   state apples cherries plums
# 1    AA    111      222   333
# 2    BB   -111     -222  -333

t(sapply(split(df.1[,3:5], df.1$state), colSums))

#    apples cherries plums
# AA    111      222   333
# BB   -111     -222  -333

t(sapply(split(df.1[,3:5], df.1$state), function(x) apply(x, 2, sum)))

#    apples cherries plums
# AA    111      222   333
# BB   -111     -222  -333

aggregate(df.1[,3:5], by=list(df.1$state), sum)

#   Group.1 apples cherries plums
# 1      AA    111      222   333
# 2      BB   -111     -222  -333

by(df.1[,3:5], df.1$state, colSums)

# df.1$state: AA
#   apples cherries    plums 
#      111      222      333 
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# df.1$state: BB
#   apples cherries    plums 
#     -111     -222     -333

with(df.1, 
     aggregate(x = list(apples   = apples, 
                        cherries = cherries,
                        plums    = plums), 
               by = list(state   = state), 
               FUN = function(x) sum(x)))

#   state apples cherries plums
# 1    AA    111      222   333
# 2    BB   -111     -222  -333

lapply(split(df.1, df.1$state), function(x) {colSums(x[,3:5])} )

# $AA
#   apples cherries    plums 
#      111      222      333 
#
# $BB
#   apples cherries    plums 
#     -111     -222     -333
```

Here is the source code for `tapply` except that I changed the line:

```
nx <- length(X)
```

to:

```
nx <- ifelse(is.vector(X), length(X), dim(X)[1])
```

This modified version of `tapply` performs the desired operation:

```
my.tapply <- function (X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE)
{
    FUN <- if (!is.null(FUN)) match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.list(INDEX)) INDEX <- list(INDEX)
    nI <- length(INDEX)
    if (!nI) stop("'INDEX' is of length zero")
    namelist <- vector("list", nI)
    names(namelist) <- names(INDEX)
    extent <- integer(nI)
    nx     <- ifelse(is.vector(X), length(X), dim(X)[1])  # replaces nx <- length(X)
    one <- 1L
    group <- rep.int(one, nx) #- to contain the splitting vector
    ngroup <- one
    for (i in seq_along(INDEX)) {
    index <- as.factor(INDEX[[i]])
    if (length(index) != nx)
        stop("arguments must have same length")
    namelist[[i]] <- levels(index)#- all of them, yes !
    extent[i] <- nlevels(index)
    group <- group + ngroup * (as.integer(index) - one)
    ngroup <- ngroup * nlevels(index)
    }
    if (is.null(FUN)) return(group)
    ans <- lapply(X = split(X, group), FUN = FUN, ...)
    index <- as.integer(names(ans))
    if (simplify && all(unlist(lapply(ans, length)) == 1L)) {
    ansmat <- array(dim = extent, dimnames = namelist)
    ans <- unlist(ans, recursive = FALSE)
    } else {
    ansmat <- array(vector("list", prod(extent)),
            dim = extent, dimnames = namelist)
    }
    if(length(index)) {
        names(ans) <- NULL
        ansmat[index] <- ans
    }
    ansmat
}

my.tapply(df.1$apples, df.1$state, function(x) {sum(x)})

#  AA   BB 
# 111 -111

my.tapply(df.1[,3:4] , df.1$state, function(x) {colSums(x)})

# $AA
#   apples cherries 
#      111      222 
#
# $BB
#   apples cherries 
#     -111     -222
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`tapply` works on a vector, for a data.frame you can use `by` (which is a wrapper for `tapply`, take a look at the code):

```
> by(df.1[,c(3:5)], df.1$state, FUN=colSums)
df.1$state: AA
  apples cherries    plums 
     111      222      333 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df.1$state: BB
  apples cherries    plums 
    -111     -222     -333
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for `by`. It uses the `INDEX` in the way that you assumed `tapply` would, by row.

```
by(df.1, df.1$state, function(x) colSums(x[,3:5]))
```

The problem with your use of `tapply` is that you were indexing the `data.frame` by *column*. (Because `data.frame` is really just a `list` of columns.) So, `tapply` complained that your index didn't match the length of your `data.frame` which is 5.

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the source code for `by`, as EDi suggested.  That code was substantially more complex than my change to the one line in `tapply`.  I have now found that `my.tapply` does not work with the more complex scenario below where `apples` and `cherries` are summed by `state` and `county`.  If I get `my.tapply` to work with this case I can post the code here later:

```
df.2 <- read.table(text = '

    state   county   apples   cherries   plums
       AA        1        1          2       3
       AA        1        1          2       3
       AA        2       10         20      30
       AA        2       10         20      30
       AA        3      100        200     300
       AA        3      100        200     300

       BB        7       -1         -2      -3
       BB        7       -1         -2      -3
       BB        8      -10        -20     -30
       BB        8      -10        -20     -30
       BB        9     -100       -200    -300
       BB        9     -100       -200    -300

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# my function works

   tapply(df.2$apples  , list(df.2$state, df.2$county), function(x) {sum(x)})
my.tapply(df.2$apples  , list(df.2$state, df.2$county), function(x) {sum(x)})

# my function works

   tapply(df.2$cherries, list(df.2$state, df.2$county), function(x) {sum(x)})
my.tapply(df.2$cherries, list(df.2$state, df.2$county), function(x) {sum(x)})

# my function does not work

my.tapply(df.2[,3:4], list(df.2$state, df.2$county), function(x) {colSums(x)})
```