# Find row sums for a subset of the columns of a matrix

Tags: r

Here is a 10 x 12 matrix:

`mat <- matrix(runif(120, 0, 1), 10)`

I am trying to find column sums for subsets of a matrix (specifically, column sums for columns 1 through 4, 5 through 8, and 9 through 12) by row. The desired output would be a 10 x 3 matrix.

I tried the approaches from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903205/sum-multiple-columns-by-group-with-tapply) using `tapply` and `by` (with detours to `rowsum` and `aggregate`), but encountered errors with all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the OP is describing is called a row sum in R:

```
# using Matthew Lundberg's example data
x <- matrix(1:36, 3,12)

g = split(seq(ncol(x)), (seq(ncol(x)) - 1) %/% 4 )
sapply(g, function(cols) rowSums( x[, cols] ))

#       0  1   2
# [1,] 22 70 118
# [2,] 26 74 122
# [3,] 30 78 126
```

---

It's typical to have grouping variables over rows/observations not columns/variables. To reach this case, the OP could transpose:

```
rowsum( t(x), (seq(ncol(x))-1) %/% 4 )
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# 0   22   26   30
# 1   70   74   78
# 2  118  122  126
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a brute-force approach, specifying each column within `apply`:

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(y) c(sum(y[1:4]), sum(y[5:8]), sum(y[9:12]))))
```

It's easier to see with non-random data, and a shorter matrix for input:

```
> x <- matrix(1:36, 3,12)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25    28    31    34
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29    32    35
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30    33    36
> t(apply(x, 1, function(y) c(sum(y[1:4]), sum(y[5:8]), sum(y[9:12]))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   22   70  118
[2,]   26   74  122
[3,]   30   78  126
```

You can also split the vector with `split`, and while this is more idiomatic for R and more flexible, it is not really more readable:

```
> t(apply(x, 1, function(y) sapply(split(y, ceiling(seq_along(y)/4)), sum)))
      1  2   3
[1,] 22 70 118
[2,] 26 74 122
[3,] 30 78 126
```

Answer (score 2):

We could convert to `array`, use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` and get the `colSums`

```
n <- 4
t(apply(array(mat, dim=c(nrow(mat), n, ncol(mat)/n)), 1, colSums))
```

---

Or another option is `melt/acast` from `library(reshape2)`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(melt(mat), Var1~(Var2-1)%/%n, value.var='value', sum)
```

The wrapper function `recast` can be used to make this compact

```
recast(mat, Var1~(Var2-1)%/%4, id.var=NULL, sum)
```

Comment: Nice. Depending on the application, the OP should consider keeping the data in an array to begin with.